# Why doesn't my Web Api proxy receive https requests when set as browser proxy, but can normally?

Tags: proxy, asp.net-web-api, http.sys

I have [written a http proxy](https://github.com/mcintyre321/WebAPI-Proxy) using WebApi.

I have it registered on port 4443, and if I enter `https://localhost:4443` into a browser, and set a breakpoint in my DelegatingHandler, it will be hit (and I get an SSL warning).

If I then set it to be the firefox proxy (see image), for SSL requests, and browse to `https://somesite.com` it is not hit - Web Api appears not to handle the call at all.

[image]

What is the browser doing differently when it uses a proxy as opposed to when it makes direct calls that causes Web Api to not handle the call?

Comment: Did you mean to say 4443?  https uses 443 by default.

Comment: 443 is used for my IIS installation, I'm trying to create a browser proxy.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize you had changed the port on the SSL proxy too.  I don't see any reason why this is not working.